# CSS3 vertical linear gradient not smooth on Chrome browser

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I want to set up a background using CSS3 gradients but it seems that Chrome has a problem rendering this gradient especially when color transitions is made on just a few pixels. There is no smooth transition between the 2 colors. When gradient is horizontally oriented it works as it supposed to.

This is the code:

```
.gradient {
background: #666 url("gradient-bg.svg");
/* Recent browsers */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top, right top,
    from(#666),
    to(#666),
    color-stop(0.02, #eff2c5),
    color-stop(0.98, #eff2c5)
    );
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    left,
    #666,
    #eff2c5 2%,
    #eff2c5 98%,
    #666
    );
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    left,
    #666,
    #eff2c5 2%,
    #eff2c5 98%,
    #666
    );
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
    left,
    #666,
    #eff2c5 2%,
    #eff2c5 98%,
    #666
    );
background-image: linear-gradient(
    left,
    #666,
    #eff2c5 2%,
    #eff2c5 98%,
    #666
    );
```

}

An example can be seen at: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47Stp/1/)

Any idea/workaround on this?

Comment: Well, what if you remove #eff2c5 2% and replace the 98% by 50%. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Nope... I really need that on both sides of div and on 2% of total width to have a gradient from #eff2c5 to #666. If you look in Firefox or even IE 11 the transition is smooth.